# Select closest date (or value) in pandas / python

Tags: python, pandas, select

How to select rows with plr_date closest to mtc_date ?
Preferably without looping over each row.
I would like to end up with rows 13, 28, 43.

I should clarify: from the set of rows with same mtc_date select one row with the closest plr_date.

```
     mtc_date  mtc_id   plr_date  plr_id  plr_measure
12 2010-03-15       1 2010-01-31       1            0
13 2010-03-15       1 2010-02-28       1            1
24 2010-06-15       2 2010-01-31       2           12
25 2010-06-15       2 2010-02-28       2           13
26 2010-06-15       2 2010-03-31       2           14
27 2010-06-15       2 2010-04-30       2           15
28 2010-06-15       2 2010-05-31       2           16
36 2010-09-15       2 2010-01-31       2           12
37 2010-09-15       2 2010-02-28       2           13
38 2010-09-15       2 2010-03-31       2           14
39 2010-09-15       2 2010-04-30       2           15
40 2010-09-15       2 2010-05-31       2           16
41 2010-09-15       2 2010-06-30       2           17
42 2010-09-15       2 2010-07-31       2           18
43 2010-09-15       2 2010-08-31       2           19
```

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

### 1 df
plr = pd.concat(\
[pd.DataFrame({'plr_date': pd.date_range("01/01/2010", "12/31/2010", freq="m"),\
'plr_id': 1 , 'plr_measure': 10}),\
pd.DataFrame({'plr_date': pd.date_range("01/01/2010", "12/31/2010", freq="m"),\
'plr_id': 2 , 'plr_measure': 20})])

#plr = plr.reindex(index=range(0, plr.shape[0]), columns=None, fill_value=0)    

plr['plr_measure']=np.arange(0, plr.shape[0])

### 2 df
mtc = pd.DataFrame({'mtc_date':pd.to_datetime(['15/01/2010','15/03/2010','15/06/2010','15/09/2010']),\
                    'mtc_id':(1,1,2,2)})

mtc = mtc.merge(plr, left_on='mtc_id', right_on='plr_id', how='left')

#select only smaller
mtc = mtc[(mtc.plr_date < mtc.mtc_date)]

#leave the bigest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, here is the updated solution using groupby.

For each group with same mtc_date, find the index that minimizes the absolute difference (in days) between mtc_date and plr_date.

```
min_indexes = mtc.groupby('mtc_date').apply(lambda x: (x['plr_date'] - x['mtc_date']).apply(lambda y: int(y.days)).abs().argmin())
```

[image]

Comment: I should clarify: from the set of rows with same mtc_date select one row with closest plr_date.

Comment: Your answer works fine for this specific example, just so happens that sorting by diff_dates works here

Comment: for mtc = pd.DataFrame({'mtc_date':pd.to_datetime(['01/03/2010','29/03/2010','28/03/2010','15/09/2010']),'mtc_id':(1,1,2,2)}) it does not work

Comment: Thanks now the question is much clearer: I updated my answer accordingly, let me know if it works.

Comment: Glad it worked. You might also consider upvoting if you found it useful ;)